# Visiting Satish Dhawan Space Center, Sriharikota as non-Indian

Tags: india, chennai, space

Satish Dhawan Space Centre (SDSC) in Sriharikota, south of Chennai, is India's main spaceport.  They have recently opened up a 5000-seat viewing gallery for launches, complete with a booking system for seats.

However, [this unofficial blog](https://coveringmiles.com/steps-to-register-for-rocket-launch-gallery-sriharikota/) suggests that entry is possible **for Indian citizens only**.  Any official sources that can confirm or deny this?  Sadly the [official site](https://www.isro.gov.in/Launch%20View%20Gallery.html) is completely useless, note that the "click here" text isn't even a link...

Comment: I think the citizenship doesn't matter; nowhere in the form do I see a mention of citizenship. It's rare that something like this would not be open to all; my guess is that the link mentioned "Indian citizens" when they simply meant "anyone". Many would write "Indians" instead which doesn't help clarify in your case; the reality is that most are unaware of the possibility of non-Indian citizens coming there as (compared to some other countries) there won't be as many non-Indians around them. To me, it's just poor wording.

Comment: @Leaderboard I wouldn't be sure about that: in my experience India is unusually prickly about nationality and there are quite a few restrictions on non-citizens, especially if you happen to be Pakistani or Bangladeshi.

Comment: That's more likely to apply to something like visiting a restricted area, not a viewing gallery.

Comment: the unofficial blog does suggest that a passport is an acceptable form of ID, which is a positive sign, but i agree that it's not 100% clear if a _foreign_ passport is okay

Comment: the completely useless official site does have a phone number and email address at the bottom; i would not be super-optimistic to get a useful reply from those but it's worth a shot

Comment: @lambshaanxy Have you tried the numbers in https://www.shar.gov.in/sdscshar/contacts_us.jsp

Comment: ISRO is very strict about security and they can deny you based on citizenship. You might have to get an advance permission.

Comment: @AnishSheela That's what I expect (hence the question), but I'm looking for a confirmed answer, not speculation.

Comment: Are you from any terrorist or enemy country of India Like Pakistan or Chin? Then you are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikivoyage](https://en.m.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sriharikota)

> Typically, without permission, one cannot enter the Satish Dhawan Space Centre (SDSC-SHAR) in Sriharikota.

> You need prior permission to get around SDSC-SHAR. Knowing an employee at the centre might help.

This is a partial answer, unfortunately I have not found anything on specifically non-Indians visiting the center. "Permission" could probably mean ID or passport.

Comment: I'm not asking about entering the centre itself, just the launch viewing gallery.

Comment: Sorry @lambshaanxy I misread your question, I shall keep looking :)